# Ler valores de uma tabela no SQLite

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, random

Estou precisando de uma ajuda na seguinte situação: Preciso pegar os valores de uma coluna no banco e gravar esses valores em uma varíavel, e que depois essa varíavel vai gerar aleatoriamente um desses dados guardados.

Abaixo a classe onde eu crio o banco:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import dominio.android.forca.data.DataBaseDescription.Contact;

class AddressBookDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Forca.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // constructor
    public AddressBookDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // creates the contacts table when the database is created
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL for creating the contacts table
        final String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + Contact.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        Contact._ID + " integer primary key, " +
                        Contact.COLUMN_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                        Contact.COLUMN_TIP + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); // create the contacts table
    }

    // normally defines how to upgrade the database when the schema changes
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }
}
```

Abaixo a classe que descreve o nome da tabela e das colunas, e outras informações do ContentProvider:

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DataBaseDescription {
    // ContentProvider's name: typically the package name
    public static final String AUTHORITY =
            "dominio.android.forca.data";

    // base URI used to interact with the ContentProvider
    private static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

    // nested class defines contents of the contacts table
    public static final class Contact implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "palavrasforca"; // table's name

        // Uri for the contacts table
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(TABLE_NAME).build();

        // column names for contacts table's columns
        public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "palavra";
        public static final String COLUMN_TIP = "dica";


        // creates a Uri for a specific contact
        public static Uri buildContactUri(long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
        }


    }
}
```

E agora, a classe que eu estou estabelecendo um método para gerar aleatóriamente o valor da coluna `COLUMN_WORD` da tabela. Aí está o problema. Não sei como resgatar esses valores e jogar dentro da `public String[] palavras = new String[] {};`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Palavras{

    public String[] palavras = new String[] {};


    public Palavras() {
    }

    public String sorteio() {
        String palavraSorteada = palavras[(int)(random()*palavras.length)];

        return palavraSorteada;
    }

    public static double random() {
        Random r = new Random();

        return r.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Desculpa os erros nos códigos acima, estou começando aprender a programar em Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar o valor random no próprio SQL 
por exemplo:

```
private void Exemplo(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT dica, palavra FROM palavrasforca ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      String dica = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dica"));
      String palavra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("palavra "));
   }
}
```

ou se quiser carregar na memória

```
   private String[] Exemplo(){
            List<String> dados = new ArrayList()
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT palavra FROM palavrasforca";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do{
                  String palavra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("palavra"));
                  dados.add(palavra) 
              }while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
            //aqui dados terá todos os valores do banco
            //converte o list para array
            return dados.toArray(new String[dados.size()]);

        }
```

Coloque o código na classe AddressBookDatabaseHelper

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito bom!! Muto obrigado! Só mais uma pergunta. Eu tenho uma classe Palavras, aí nela eu tenho um vetor de String pronto. Como eu pegaria esse select e jogaria nela?

Comment: Como você não sabe a quantidade de itens que tem no banco, recomendo usar o `List<String>` pois nele você só chama o `.add`, se no final você quiser passar para um array de String pode fazer o seguinte `palavras = dados.toArray(new String[dados.size()])`

Comment: Estou tendo um problema. Pois fiz pelo segundo jeito e retornei um List<String>, e na classe Palavras ele não está reconhecendo a classe AddressBookDatabaseHelper quando chamo    `lista_palavras = Exemplo();`  O que poderia ser?

Comment: Editei a resposta, o método Exemplo retorna "void", só adaptar para retornar String[] e fazer a conversão embaixo.

Comment: A última coisa kkk. Como posso fazer pra identificar a dica da palavra que foi randomizada.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma consulta no banco `SELECT dica FROM palavrasforca WHERE palavra = 'palavraexemplo'`, do mesmo jeito que faz a consulta e no cursor só alterar para `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dica"))`